# How to create a jquery mobile ordered list with list symbols set to outside?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<ol data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <p>description</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

The result is:

```
   1.
   Heading 
   Description
```

I want:

```
    1.    Heading
          Description
```

I would have thought I could have stuck list-style-position:outside as an inline style with the li tag. No luck. If I remove the listview data-role, the style is applied correctly.

Some how the listview date-role is manipulating the styles, I can't figure out how though... I've searched for the list-style-position line in the jquery mobile css and js files and no results were returned, what is going on here?

Some help please?

PS. using jquery mobile 1.0a4.1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add some custom CSS

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/7Bn2z/43/
Live Example #2: http://jsfiddle.net/7Bn2z/48/ (Fixed the layout a little)

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="b" id="jqm-home">
    <div data-role="content"> 
        <ol data-role="listview">
            <li>
                <span>
                    <span class="oi-li-heading">heading</span>
                    <span class="oi-li-desc">description</span>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.oi-li-heading {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: .6em 0;
}

.oi-li-desc {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: -.5em 0 .6em;
}
```

UPDATE:

If you have chrome installed you can right click the example page here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Bn2z/49/ and inspect element. As you can see jQM adds a to of CSS

So in the example we start off with:

```
<ol data-role="listview">
    <li>
        <h3>heading</h3>
        <p>description</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

And jQM adds it's tags to this:

```
<ol data-role="listview" class="ui-listview">
    <li class="ui-li ui-li-static ui-body-c">
        <h3 class="ui-li-heading">heading</h3>
        <p class="ui-li-desc">description</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Hrm, your example appears to work in jsfiddle but when I copy it over to my project it doesn't. I'm using jquery.js v1.4.4 and jquery-mobile.js vs1.0a4.1. I noticed jsfiddle makes no mention of jquery mobile.

Comment: actually I'm using jquery.js v1.5.2 and jquery-mobile.js v1.0.a4.1 also I changed the CSS in the second example a little

Comment: Ok, the code works. At first I was using your original example. I'm hoping for a better solution, I don't like relying on padding for aligning things. If you view the code in several different browsers it the output will not be the same. I was hoping for a answer as to why setting list-style-position to the li takes doesn't work and how to override it.

Comment: Hmm, It does work except when you add another tag like the <h3> or <p> tags, this throws off the display and sets the new elements under the number instead of keeping the number to the left of the elements. I will raise this as an issue and see what they jQM devs say. You can follow the issue here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1609

Comment: Here is the example of the number list working: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/lists-readonly-inset.html but as you can see it display inline. When adding the header and description tags this also add CSS which throws off the display of the ordered list

Comment: Yep, because the list display needs to be set to "outside" so that it doesn't interfere with the flow of heading and description. It's something that needs to be addressed...

Comment: jQM just updated the issue, not going to be addressed by them. Looks like you need a custom CSS solution

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going use ordered lists with headers *AND descriptions until the problem is fixed.

Comment: I am also having a problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when creating a numbered list in my jquery mobile app. The css below fixed the problem for me:

```
  ol.ui-listview .ui-li-heading {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -1.3em;
    text-indent: 1.3em;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```